# What's the difference of naming a polynomial ring as $\mathbb{C}\{ x,y\}$ and $\mathbb{C} [x,y]$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, notation

I sometimes see both notations and I am led (maybe misled) to believe that they are the same thing. What is the formal difference between both of them? Or there isn't any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbb{C}\{x,y\}$ is the ring of convergent power series in $x,y$; $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is the ring of polynomials in $x,y$.  The third related object you often see is $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$; this is the ring of *formal* power series in $x,y$.

Comment: This makes things cleares than I hoped :) I was having this doubt, since the material I'm reading said $dim_{\mathbb{C}}\frac{\mathcal{O}}{a\mathcal{O}+b\mathcal{O}}$ is finite under some conditions, where $a,b\in\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{C}\{ x,y\}$, $\mathcal{O}$ the ring of function germs at a singularity.

Comment: I'm glad it's helpful!  Yes, you could also call $\mathbb{C}\{x,y\}$ the ring of (analytic) function germs at the origin.